# Find all lists of sublists that when concatenated give a given list

Tags: prolog

I wrote this function that given as a first parameter a list of lists, it generates in the second parameter the result of concatenating all the lists.

```
appall([],[]).
appall([H|T],V) :- appall(T,V1), append(H,V1,V).
```

However, I want it to work the other way around - `appall(X,[1,2,3])` - to give me `X = [[],[1,2,3]]` then `X=[[1],[2,3]]` and so on. This doesn't work because the call `appall(T, V1)` doesn't decrease.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
split([],[]).
split([Head|Tail],[[Head]|Split]) :-
    split(Tail,Split).
split([Head|Tail],[[Head|List]|Split]) :-
    split(Tail,[List|Split]).
```

For example:

```
?- split([1,2,3,4],Lists), split(Recover,Lists).
Lists = [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1], [2], [3, 4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1], [2, 3], [4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1], [2, 3, 4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1, 2], [3], [4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4]],
Recover = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

This solution is based on the following observation. I will refer to the flattened list as the *input list* and the unflattened list as the *output list*. In the recursive case, the input list has the form `[H|T]` and `split(T,R)` succeeds by assumption. There are three cases to consider.

1. If `R = []` we can begin constructing a new list whose last element is `H`.
2. If `R = [_|_]` we can begin constructing a new list whose last element is `H`.
3. If `R = [L|_]` we can continue constructing `L` by prepending `H` to `L`.

In each case, we obtain valid output lists. The first two cases are implemented by the second clause of `split/2` (it doesn't matter whether `R = []` or `R = [_|_]`) and the third by the third clause.